# Gatsby + Netlify CMS - error Your site's "gatsby-node.js" must set the page path when creating a page

Tags: reactjs, gatsby, netlify-cms

It's saying that path is null and the context > slug is null. However they are defined in my gatsby-node.js file.

It was working locally, now it's not. Trying to figure out why this is happening. Searched Google and S/O, can't seem to find an answer.

Here's the error below when deploying to Netlify:

```
10:51:57 AM: error Your site's "gatsby-node.js" must set the page path when creating a page.
10:51:57 AM: The page object passed to createPage:
10:51:57 AM: {
10:51:57 AM:     "path": null,
10:51:57 AM:     "component": "/opt/build/repo/src/templates/blogTemplate.js",
10:51:57 AM:     "context": {
10:51:57 AM:         "slug": null
10:51:57 AM:     }
10:51:57 AM: }
```

My front matter markdown in my blog post files are:

```
---
title: example
slug: /posts/example/
date: 2019-03-26T23:53:24.128Z
excerpt: >-
  example description
---
```

My gatsby-node.js:

```
exports.createPages = async ({ actions, graphql, reporter }) => {
  const { createPage } = actions
  const blogPostTemplate = require.resolve(`./src/templates/blogTemplate.js`)
  const result = await graphql(`
    {
      allMarkdownRemark(
        sort: { order: DESC, fields: [frontmatter___date] }
        limit: 1000
      ) {
        edges {
          node {
            frontmatter {
              slug
            }
          }
        }
      }
    }
  `)
  // Handle errors
  if (result.errors) {
    reporter.panicOnBuild(`Error while running GraphQL query.`)
    return
  }
  result.data.allMarkdownRemark.edges.forEach(({ node }) => {
    createPage({
      path: node.frontmatter.slug,
      component: blogPostTemplate,
      context: {
        // additional data can be passed via context
        slug: node.frontmatter.slug,
      },
    })
  })
}
```

My blogTemplate.js file:

```
import React from "react"
import { Container, Row, Col } from "reactstrap"
import { Helmet } from "react-helmet"
import Nav from "../../components/Nav/nav"
import InnerHero from "../../components/innerHero/innerHero"
import CTA from "../../components/CTA/cta"
import Footer from "../../components/Footer/footer"
import { graphql } from "gatsby"
export default function Template({
  data, // this prop will be injected by the GraphQL query below.
}) {
  const { markdownRemark } = data // data.markdownRemark holds your post data
  const { frontmatter, html } = markdownRemark
  return (
    <>
      <Helmet>
        <title>{frontmatter.title} - Infused</title>
        <meta
          name="description"
          content={frontmatter.excerpt}
        />
      </Helmet>
      <Nav/>
      <InnerHero title={frontmatter.title}/>
      <section className="inner-content">
        <Container className="single-blog">
        <Row>
          <Col lg="12">
              <div className="blog-post">
                <div
                  className="blog-post-content"
                  dangerouslySetInnerHTML={{ __html: html }}
                />
                </div>
            </Col>
          </Row>
        </Container>
      </section>
      <CTA/>
      <Footer/>
    </>
  )
}
export const pageQuery = graphql`
  query($slug: String!) {
    markdownRemark(frontmatter: { slug: { eq: $slug } }) {
      html
      frontmatter {
        date(formatString: "MMMM DD, YYYY")
        slug
        title
        excerpt
      }
    }
  }
`
```

Comment: After some reading, it seems a Netlify cache issue related to mismatching version of dependencies. Try to upgrade your dependencies and build your site locally to check if you can reproduce the issue on your machine.

Comment: @FerranBuireu tried removing node_modules, reinstalling node_modules and still getting the same error.

Comment: What Node version are running both, your local and Netlify?